# Heroku Shows Application Error(H10) While Deploying a NLP model

Tags: python, heroku, nlp

I am Deploying an NLP model to deployment using flask on Heroku. After a successful build, I get an H10 error.
**Build**

```
-----> Python app detected
-----> No change in requirements detected, installing from cache
-----> Installing pip 20.1.1, setuptools 47.1.1 and wheel 0.34.2
-----> Installing SQLite3
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> Downloading NLTK corpora…
 !     'nltk.txt' not found, not downloading any corpora
 !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 158.6M
-----> Launching...
       Released v8
       https://nlp-hub.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

I know that it is because of my app crashed but I don't know how to solve it hero below is a glance of my logs.

```
2020-11-14T05:05:10.175489+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
2020-11-14T05:05:10.176397+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:10 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-14T05:05:10.522025+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-11-14T05:05:10.522239+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:10 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2020-11-14T05:05:10.613651+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2020-11-14T05:05:10.680671+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-11-14T05:05:10.683831+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-11-14T05:05:14.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-11-14T05:05:20.079376+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2020-11-14T05:05:22.443588+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
2020-11-14T05:05:22.444191+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:57434 (4)
2020-11-14T05:05:22.444280+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:22 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-11-14T05:05:22.448761+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:22 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-11-14T05:05:22.529825+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:22 +0000] [11] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 11
2020-11-14T05:05:23.041983+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-11-14T05:05:27.721874+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator MultinomialNB from version 0.22.1 when using version 0.23.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2020-11-14T05:05:27.721891+00:00 app[web.1]: UserWarning)
2020-11-14T05:05:27.727491+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator MultinomialNB from version 0.22.1 when using version 0.23.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2020-11-14T05:05:27.727492+00:00 app[web.1]: UserWarning)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.009431+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version 0.22.1 when using version 0.23.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2020-11-14T05:05:28.009443+00:00 app[web.1]: UserWarning)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.014102+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:334: UserWarning: Trying to unpickle estimator CountVectorizer from version 0.22.1 when using version 0.23.2. This might lead to breaking code or invalid results. Use at your own risk.
2020-11-14T05:05:28.014103+00:00 app[web.1]: UserWarning)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200006+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:28 +0000] [11] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200008+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200013+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200014+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200014+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200015+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200015+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200016+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200016+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200016+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200017+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200017+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200018+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200019+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200019+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 24, in <module>
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200020+00:00 app[web.1]: moviecv=pickle.load(open('moviecv.pkl','rb'))
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200020+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.[2020-11-14 05:05:28 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200021+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200021+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200021+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200022+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200022+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200022+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200023+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200023+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200023+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200042+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200042+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200043+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200043+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200043+00:00 app[web.1]: __import__(module)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200044+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/app.py", line 24, in <module>
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200044+00:00 app[web.1]: moviecv=pickle.load(open('moviecv.pkl','rb'))
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200051+00:00 app[web.1]: _pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, 'v'.
2020-11-14T05:05:28.200052+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-14T05:05:28.201103+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:28 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.201104+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-11-14 05:05:28 +0000] [11] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.511862+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-14T05:05:28.511913+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 210, in run
2020-11-14T05:05:28.512243+00:00 app[web.1]: self.sleep()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.512274+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 360, in sleep
2020-11-14T05:05:28.512652+00:00 app[web.1]: ready = select.select([self.PIPE[0]], [], [], 1.0)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.512681+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2020-11-14T05:05:28.512954+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.512986+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513419+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513513+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513595+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513596+00:00 app[web.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513596+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513621+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513647+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513797+00:00 app[web.1]: sys.exit(run())
2020-11-14T05:05:28.513823+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 61, in run
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514014+00:00 app[web.1]: WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514018+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 223, in run
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514278+00:00 app[web.1]: super(Application, self).run()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514278+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514456+00:00 app[web.1]: Arbiter(self).run()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514457+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 232, in run
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514711+00:00 app[web.1]: self.halt(reason=inst.reason, exit_status=inst.exit_status)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.514712+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 345, in halt
2020-11-14T05:05:28.515052+00:00 app[web.1]: self.stop()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.515053+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 393, in stop
2020-11-14T05:05:28.515411+00:00 app[web.1]: time.sleep(0.1)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.515412+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 245, in handle_chld
2020-11-14T05:05:28.515668+00:00 app[web.1]: self.reap_workers()
2020-11-14T05:05:28.515668+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 525, in reap_workers
2020-11-14T05:05:28.516105+00:00 app[web.1]: raise HaltServer(reason, self.WORKER_BOOT_ERROR)
2020-11-14T05:05:28.516129+00:00 app[web.1]: gunicorn.errors.HaltServer: <HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3>
2020-11-14T05:05:28.602582+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-14T05:05:28.651337+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-11-14T05:05:36.631231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nlp-hub.herokuapp.com request_id=e3660c35-6db1-42ba-8f5f-080622c1ea27 fwd="223.188.115.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-14T05:05:37.728300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nlp-hub.herokuapp.com request_id=a71ec4f4-2f2f-493b-aaa8-7332c0d44a7a fwd="223.188.115.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

What I think the main problem is

```
2020-11-14T05:05:36.631231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=nlp-hub.herokuapp.com request_id=e3660c35-6db1-42ba-8f5f-080622c1ea27 fwd="223.188.115.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-14T05:05:37.728300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=nlp-hub.herokuapp.com request_id=a71ec4f4-2f2f-493b-aaa8-7332c0d44a7a fwd="223.188.115.243" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Please help me solving this I am new to Heroku logs.

**UPDATED**
After adding nltk.txt file now it is showing another error

````
error. ``` /app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py:125: RuntimeWarning: 'nltk.downloader' found in sys.modules after import of package 'nltk', but prior to execution of 'nltk.downloader'; this may result in unpredictable behaviour
  warn(RuntimeWarning(msg))
[nltk_data] Error loading wordnet : Package 'wordnet\r' not found in
[nltk_data]     index
Error installing package. Retry? [n/y/e]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 2538, in <module>
    halt_on_error=options.halt_on_error,
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py", line 790, in download
    choice = input().strip()
````

Here is my nltk.txt file

```
punkt
stopwords
```

Please help me id anyone knows the answer???

Comment: are you able to run the model on the local machine?

Comment: Yes It is running On my Local Machine

Answer (score 0):

you're missing the `nltk.txt` file.
If you want to use simple functionalities like pos_tag, tokenizer, stemming, etc. then you can do the following steps

1. mention nltk in requirements.txt
2. mention following modules in nltk.txt

- wordnet
- pros_cons
- reuters
- hmm_treebank_pos_tagger
- maxent_treebank_pos_tagger
- universal_tagset
- punkt
- averaged_perceptron_tagger_ru
- averaged_perceptron_tagger
- snowball_data
- rslp
- porter_test
- vader_lexicon
- treebank
- dependency_treebank

above mentioned are some example you can put only your modules in the application

for more info refer [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-nltk)

Comment: I've already added nltk in my requirment.txt file and now I also added nltk.txt but it still shows me some error.

Comment: no, you also have to create `nltk.txt` file and have to mention modules that you using regarding the nltk, I think the link I provided has more details please refer to it