# Heroku deployment of NLP model showing error ( app runs fine locally )

Tags: python, heroku, nlp, tokenize, mlops

I have deployed my Flask App ( NLP model ) on Heroku. I was basically a price prediction model where some columns were in Japanese where I applied NLP + Nagisa Library for tokenization and some columns were numerical data.
I pickled vectorizers and the model and Finally added them to my Flask API. But after deployment when I added the values in the frontend and clicked on Predict button, the result is not getting displayed.
This is the exact error I am facing.

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxUzt.png)

The exact code of Tokenizer_jp is :

```
def tokenize_jp(doc):
        doc = nagisa.tagging(doc)
        return doc.words
```

I am not able to figure out how to fix this?

Comment: is this the same question as yours? [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64831158/heroku-shows-application-errorh10-while-deploying-a-nlp-model)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.